# Regex to get substring from right to left

Tags: regex

I want to use a regex in PowerShell to remove certain substrings from inside an XML file. This file somewhat looks like this:

```
<Name>FixedString1 FixedString2 VariableString</Name><Name>FixedString1 SearchString VariableString</Name>
```

So in the file there are multiple occasions of "FixedString1" and "FixedString2" inside "Name" tags. The "VariableString" is different in every occasion.

The regex needs to find "SearchString", use this as the starting point to go backwards (right to left) until the closing bracket ">" of the "Name" tag, including "FixedString1" and the "SearchString" itself. So the output of the regex needs to be

```
FixedString1 SearchString
```

which I can later delete from the XML file using PowerShell, so that I'm left with

```
<Name>VariableString</Name>
```

in the XML file.

What I tried so far in regex101.com is

```
FixedString1 .*(?<= SearchString )
```

but this regex matches from the first occasion of "FixedString1" in the file, meaning left to right, until "SearchString":

```
FixedString1 FixedString2 VariableString</Name><Name>FixedString1 SearchString
```

I want it to find the "SearchString" and from there go to the left until the first occasion of "FixedString1", including both strings.

Can you please help me with this? Thanks!

Comment: What platform/framework/programming language are you using?

Comment: What precisely do you want to match? You are using a lookbehind assertion in your regex, so `SearchString` won't be included in your match - but you say it should ?

Comment: @collapsar it's a lookbehind not a lookahead, so it's a very convoluted way to match up to SearchString included (it will match up to the 0-width segment that follows SearchString)

Comment: @Aaron: I am so dumb. Of course, thanks

Comment: @collapsar that was seriously not obvious, no need to beat yourself up over it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the following :

```
FixedString1[^>]*SearchString
```

It matches from `FixedString1` up to `SearchString`, but only strings that do not include `>`.

[regex101 test](https://regex101.com/r/F8hUSN/1)

Comment: Wow, thanks Aaron, that was incredibly fast and useful! =) It works.